# Laravel: using url parameter for controller action

Tags: php, laravel, routes

sorry i'm a laravel newbie - here's my route code:

```
Route::get('shop/{id}', function($id)
{
});
```

`$id` represents the shop category id and i would like to pass id to a controller-action like `shop\StartController@showarticles`

i'm only used to this syntax:

```
Route::get('/', 'shop\StartController@show');
```

how would i do that?
thanks

Comment: It can be as simple as this: `Route::get('shop/{id}', array('as' => 'shop', 'uses' => 'ShopController@index'))`

Comment: You can write it the same way as your main, no need of function(){}

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it as a parameter like this (assuming Laravel 5.1 is used):

### Controller:

```
class StartController extends Controller
....
public function show($id)
{
   //add controller logic
}
```

### Routes:

```
//Asuming that the namespace `shop` is loaded
Route::get('/', 'StartController@show');
```

Check out more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing)

Answer (score 2):

you can easily pass the id to controller

```
Route::get('shop/{id}','UserController@show');
```

Your controller

```
class UserController extends BaseController {


public function show($id)
{
    echo "hi its my first exercise in laravel".$id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure for your route and call the controller like this:

```
Route::get('shop/{id}', function($id)
    return App::make('StartController')->showarticles($id);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller would be like

```
Route::get('shop/{id}', 'shop\StartController@showarticles');
```

and your class function would be like

```
class StartController extends Controller
....
public function show($id)
```

or incase you are using latest version

```
class StartController extends Controller
....
public function show(Request $request, $id)
```